# C# Looping through nested LINQ select statements

Tags: c#, linq, nested

The sample below is parsing an XML document then looping through the members and storing them in a list  of objects (The data ultimately ends up in an SQL database):

```
public static void Parse(XDocument xml)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://somenamespace.com/ns";

    var Locations =
        from Continents in xml.Descendants(ns + "Continent")
        from Countries in Continents.Elements(ns + "Country")
        select new
        {
            Continent1 = (string) Continents.Element(ns + "Europe"),
            Country1 = (string) Countries.Element(ns + "United_Kingdom"),
            Cities = from Cities in Countries.Elements(ns + "City")
                select new
                {
                    City1 = (string) Cities.Element(ns + "London")
                }
        };

    List<Location> locationColl = new List<Location>();

    loc_Entity_FrameworkContainer context = new loc_Entity_FrameworkContainer();

    var i = 0;

    foreach (var location in Locations)
    {
        Location l = new Location();
        locationColl.Add(l);

        locationColl[i].Continent = (string) location.Continent1;
        locationColl[i].Country = (string) location.Country1;
        locationColl[i].City = (string) location.City1; // Can't access "City1"

        context.Location.Add(locationColl[i]);
        i++;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The statement: `locationColl[i].City = (string)location.City1;` 
doesn't find "City1". (This is the issue, I can't access all the members from "Locations" in one loop)

Location Class:

```
namespace locationProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Location
    {
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:ns="http://somenamespace.com/ns">
   <ns:Continent>
      <ns:Europe>21c99a56-4b3d-4571-802a-76cdb6b81a01</ns:Europe>
      <ns:Country>
         <ns:United_Kingdom>eb2e9eec-dc3b-4636-bcf5-dba0024e62f3</ns:United_Kingdom>
         <ns:City>
            <ns:London>109b48ec-d829-4a87-b200-4dc9a94db48c</ns:London>
         </ns:City>
      </ns:Country>
   </ns:Continent>
   <ns:Continent>
      <ns:Europe>a11ed925-dc0d-4dfd-b1c2-52eb697ad689</ns:Europe>
      <ns:Country>
         <ns:United_Kingdom>a61d02ef-7b80-4390-926a-49c6d9af9634</ns:United_Kingdom>
         <ns:City>
            <ns:London>dbb9c5cc-b08f-4223-b32c-acb4ed9ce97c</ns:London>
         </ns:City>
      </ns:Country>
   </ns:Continent>
</feed>
```

I'm trying to find a way of looping through all the elements (Continent1, Country1, City1) that doesn't involve multiple loops and doesn't break the nested structure of the LINQ statements.

There are questions on here similar to this one, but I haven't found one I understand well enough to integrate with my code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Location` class and an example of your xml?

Comment: If you share your XML structure, it is possible people can provide better and more complete answers.

Comment: The Location class and an XML example has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Your anonymous type contained in the Locations list has a `.Cities` property that contains a `City1` member:

```
Cities = from Cities in Countries.Elements(ns + "City")
    select new
    {
        City1 = (string) Cities.Element(ns + "London")
    }
```

Try this:

```
var Locations =
    from Continents in xml.Descendants(ns + "Continent")
    from Countries in Continents.Elements(ns + "Country")
    from Cities in Countries.Elements(ns + "City")
    select new
    {
        Continent1 = (string) Continents.Element(ns + "Europe"),
        Country1 = (string) Countries.Element(ns + "United Kingdom"),
        City1 = (string) Cities.Element(ns + "London")
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This method does allow me to keep all the elements in one loop, however, if for example a Continent doesn't contain a Country or City element, it won't return that Continent. The nested LINQ structure I am using still returns a Continent even if that Continent doesn't contain a Country or City. So the question is, how do I keep the nested LINQ structure and have access to all its members in one loop?

Comment: @Cryptonaut Just use multiple loops.  It's clearly warranted here.  While you *could* technically avoid it, you're only making thing *harder* on you in order to do it.

Comment: @Servy Even so, how would I access the nested members in another loop?

Comment: @Cryptonaut You put one `foreach` inside of another: `foreach(var continent in xml.Descendants(ns + "Continent")){ foreach(var country in continent.Elements(ns + "Country")) {} }`